# Conditional, partial, typesetting inside equations

Tags: math-mode, lyx, align, conditionals

I would like to be able to partially typeset only some parts of equations according to some flag. An example use would be that I have a long calculation over several lines, which when I print for myself would like in full, but when sending to others would like to only show the first and bottom line, for clarity.

I tried defining `\newif\detailed` and putting `\ifdetailed` and `\fi` around the lines I want to control; however, this only works inside `gather` environments and not inside `align`. (It works inside `align` only if the `\if` and `fi` are on the same "line", but that produces ghost lines if I want to hide an entire line).

Lyx's branches feature was also no good, since it be placed inside math-mode to contain only part of the equation.

A simple case is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newif\ifdetailed  
\detailedfalse
\begin{document}
Test
\begin{align}
  A 
  \ifdetailed  
  &=a+b\\ 
  &=a+b+a-a\\ 
  \fi
  &=2a+b-a
\end{align}
Test223
\end{document}
```

Which produce a control sequence error. As pointed out by StephenH, changing it to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newif\ifdetailed  \detailedtrue
%\detailedfalse  %% Uncomment to remove detailed results
\begin{document}
Test
\begin{align}
  A&=a+b\\
  \ifdetailed
  &=a+b+a-a\\
  \fi
  &=2a+b-a
\end{align}
Test
\end{document}
```

solved the problem. However, this does not permit the ability the shrink it down completely to a single line.

Comment: Could you please add an MWE of what you tried?

Comment: Sure, just what is an MWE?

Comment: MWE is an [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx), beginning with `\documentclass` and ending in `\end{document}`.  Please help us, to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to hide the unused `&` from the parser:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newif\ifdetailed  
\detailedfalse
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\detailed}[1]{%
  \ifdetailed
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \fi
  {#1}%
}

\begin{document}

Test
\begin{align}
A
\detailed{
  &=a+b\\
  &=a+b+a-a\\
}
&=2a+b-a
\end{align}
Test\detailedtrue
\begin{align}
A
\detailed{
  &=a+b\\
  &=a+b+a-a\\
}
&=2a+b-a
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice, but why do you need `\expandafter\@firstofone` in the detailed case?

Comment: @StefanH This gets rid of `\else...\fi`

Comment: So `\expandafter` takes care of `\else...\fi` and `\@firstofone` expands `{#1}` and gives the content of `#1`?

Comment: @StefanH Yes, but the main feature is that the braces keep the parser quiet.

Comment: It's a nice construction, I will try to remember it.

Comment: Can this be easily used inside Lyx, which I use to edit my document? As far as I know, it's a bit difficult to enter raw code inside it's math-mode environment. Also, can you please elaborate a bit about the macros you use? I'm not familiar with them.

Answer (score 3):

I get it working with `\newif` and `align`, but it might also be worth looking at the `comment` package or `ifthen` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newif\ifdetailed  \detailedtrue
%\detailedfalse  %% Uncomment to remove detailed results
\begin{document}
Test
\begin{align}
  A&=a+b\\
  \ifdetailed
  &=a+b+a-a\\
  \fi
  &=2a+b-a
\end{align}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently, the placement of my `\if` and `\fi`caused it trouble. It was a result of trying the catch the line-breaks in the Lyx UI.  Your suggestion seems to have solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, if I try to also hide the first line after the `=&` (so to make it all print as a single line), I also get an error.